# Как решить проблему с установкой JSHint на Windows

Tags: javascript, jshint

[image: Как решить проблему с установкой JSHint на Windows.]
Как решить проблему с установкой JSHint на Windows.

Comment: А с какой целью Вы там вводите символ `$`?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это ошибка копирования команды из иллюстрации установки для Linux (где `$` это просто знак приглашения командной строки). Попробуйте вводить без `$`. Просто `npm install -g jshint`.

Comment: Тоже самое что и до этого

Comment: Можете показать скриншот командной строки?